# if exists update else insert query not working mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data if data exists I need to update data .i have a query but when I execute this query in phpmyadmin am getting errors

2 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "KEY" at position 224)
>
> An expression was expected. (near "SET" at position 235)

below is my query:

```
INSERT INTO usr_data (usr_id, login, firstname, gender, street, zipcode, country, phone_mobile, email)
VALUES('265', '100236', 'gouni', 'M', 'jlnklmana', '502103', 'telangana', '+60123654', 'email@email.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET login=100236,usr_id=265,firstname=gouni,gender=M,street=jlnklmanahghg,zipcode=502103,country=telangana,phone_mobile=+60123654,email=email@email.com
```

Comment: Try remove the `SET` after `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the word SET

```
INSERT INTO usr_data (usr_id, login, firstname, gender, street, zipcode, country, phone_mobile, email)
VALUES('265', '100236', 'gouni', 'M', 'jlnklmana', '502103', 'telangana', '+60123654', 'email@email.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  login='100236',usr_id='265',firstname='gouni',gender='M',street='jlnklmanahghg',zipcode='502103',country='telangana',phone_mobile='+60123654',
email='email@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Corrected query :

```
INSERT INTO usr_data 
(usr_id, login, firstname, gender, street, zipcode, country, phone_mobile, email)
VALUES
('265', '100236', 'gouni', 'M', 'jlnklmana', '502103', 'telangana', '+60123654', 'email@email.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE
login='100236',usr_id='265',firstname='gouni',gender='M',street='jlnklmanahghg',zipcode='502103',country='telangana',phone_mobile='+60123654',email='email@email.com'
```

You have to remove `SET` keyword from your query.

**GENERAL SYNTAX:**

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "KEY" at position 228)
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 247)
Unexpected token. (near "100236" at position 248)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 254)
Unexpected token. (near "usr_id" at position 255)
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 261) getting this error

Comment: Try now i edited my answer